# How to stop iframe video after closing modal in angular

Tags: angular, iframe

component.html

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"
      aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="static">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" 
              (click)="closeYt()">
              <span aria-hidden="true" style="color: white;">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <iframe #player frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="1"
              title="YouTube video player" width="1000" height="360"
              src="you tube video url">
            </iframe>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I am using bootstrap 4 modal and angular version 11

component.ts

```
@ViewChild('player') player: ElementRef<HTMLInputElement>

closeYt() {
    What should i do next to pause or stop video?
}
```

After modal close button i've called closeYt() function where i want to stop or pause the video.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: did you try the obvious? `(click)="player.pause()"`

Comment: @Ayyash Yes, but it's not working

Comment: Please mention which different things you tried and is any errors/exemptions you encountered. It will help people to answer you.

Comment: As @Ayyash said i tried this but getting pause() method not found error

Comment: "not working" isn't descriptive. Anyways did you notice that you are trying to pause an "iframe" element?

Comment: I found one solution hide and show the iframe div this is working for me as i expected idk this is correct way or not :)